# Issue with Segue sender Object "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am programing an app, I've created a `MainTableviewVontrolller.h` &  `MainTableviewVontrolller.m` files with corresponding object file for Json storing data named as `Youga.h` and `Youga.m` 
in this above `MainTableviewVontrolller.m` I've to extract some data from web, which works perfectly. now I've to move advanced towards another scene containing `DetailTableViewController.h` & `DetailTableViewController.m` on storyboard via `Showdetail` Segue, Here I've to pass some parameters as I needs to select those indexes in my array which containing ycategoryName is equal to earlier MainTableviewVontrolller.m selected row's index path name `yougaName`

I am using two different web services

1. http://yoga.lifehealthinfo.com/api/yoga_list/categories  with Primary keys ID  and Name
2. http://yoga.lifehealthinfo.com/api/yoga_list/all with matching keys category `category_id` and `category_name`

the thing which I am trying to accomplish is that I am willing to show selected row's corresponding data from second web services Json file. 
here goes error which I am having on console.

```
2016-08-10 11:54:07.904 iYouga[622:21074] -[UITableViewController getCategory:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb195808490
2016-08-10 11:54:07.951 iYouga[622:21074] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController getCategory:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb195808490'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103933e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001033acdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010393c48d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010388990a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001038894b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   iYouga                              0x0000000102ea90bf -[MainTableViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] + 351
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000104409f01 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 369
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000104409d5f -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010440a023 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000103e23cee -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1775
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000103e23fb3 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 388
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000103cec4a2 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 317
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000103cffc01 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 95
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000103d0baf3 _afterCACommitHandler + 90
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010385f367 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010385f2d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103854f2b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103854828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001070f0ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000103ce0610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    20  iYouga                              0x0000000102ea98df main + 111
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010606f92d start + 1
    22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

And now review `MainTableViewController.m` file

```
#import "MainTableViewController.h"
#import "Youga.h"
#import "DetailTableViewController.h"

#define getDataUrl @"http://yoga.lifehealthinfo.com/api/yoga_list/categories"

@interface MainTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainTableViewController
@synthesize jsonArray, yougaArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     [self retrieveData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return yougaArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Youga * YougaObject;
    YougaObject = [yougaArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = YougaObject.yougaName;

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    // Configure the cell...

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        //get the object for selected row
        Youga *object = [yougaArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] getCategory:object];
    }}


-(void) retrieveData{
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataUrl];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSDictionary *dataJSON = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSArray *allCategoriesJSON = [dataJSON objectForKey:@"categories"];

    yougaArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < allCategoriesJSON.count; i ++)
    {
        NSDictionary *aCategoryJSON = [allCategoriesJSON objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *yId = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString *yName = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *yDescription = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"description"];
        NSString *yImage = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"image"];
        [yougaArray addObject:[[Youga alloc] initWithYougaId:yId andYougaName:yName andYougaDescpription:yDescription andYougaImage:yImage]];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

And here is my `DetailTableViewController.m` file

```
#import "DetailTableViewController.h"
#import "Categories.h"
#import "MainTableViewController.h"

#define kUrl @"http://yoga.lifehealthinfo.com/api/yoga_list/all"

@interface DetailTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailTableViewController
@synthesize categoryArray, currentCategory;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

 [self extractData];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return categoryArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"maincell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Categories * categoryObject;
    categoryObject = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = categoryObject.ycategoryName;

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    // Configure the cell...


    return cell;
}

-(void) getCategory:(id)yougaObject{

    currentCategory = yougaObject;

}

-(void) extractData{
    NSURL * curl = [NSURL URLWithString:kUrl];
    NSData * cdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:curl];
    NSDictionary *myDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:cdata options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSDictionary *cdataJson = [myDict objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSArray *allImagesJson = [cdataJson objectForKey:@"Images"];
    categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(int i = 0; i<allImagesJson.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *aCategoryImages = [allImagesJson objectAtIndex:i];

            NSString * cId = [aCategoryImages objectForKey:@"id"];
            NSString * cTitle = [aCategoryImages objectForKey:@"tite"];
            NSString * cDescription = [aCategoryImages objectForKey:@"description"];
            NSString * cImage = [aCategoryImages objectForKey:@"image"];
            NSString * cDate = [aCategoryImages objectForKey:@"date_created"];
            NSString * ycName = [aCategoryImages objectForKey:@"category_name"];
            NSString * ycId = [aCategoryImages objectForKey:@"category_id"];

            [categoryArray addObject:[[Categories alloc]initWithCategoryId: cId andCategoryTitle:cTitle andCategoryDescription:cDescription andCategoryImage:cImage andCategoryDate:cDate andYcategoryId:ycId andYCategoryName:ycName]];

        }
 [self.tableView reloadData];

}

@end
```

Could anyone resolve this issue ???

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably comes from your Storyboard. Are you sure that you correctly change the class of the segue destination view controller to be your custom DetailTableViewController. It seems that storyboard instantiate a classic UITableViewController instead of your custom class, hence the unrecognized selector...

[image: Here is how...]

Comment: Thanks @Florian for your time, & I was really forgot to give class name to my view controller's property. But still I've an issue,  in `DetailViewController.m` in cell declaration there `yCategoryName`  which is `cell.textLabel.text = categoryObject.ycategoryName; ` when I executed it displayed same category in cells but actually I was required `cell.textLabel.text = categoryObject.categoryTitle; ` but when I replaced this 'yCategoryName' with 'categoryTitle' it gives me empty cells.... but giving required numbers of cells with empty texted... any idea??? why it is behaving like this?

Comment: can you add a breakpoint on the line " cell.textLabel.text = categoryObject.ycategoryName; " and inspect your categoryObject to see if all the data are here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get reference to the destination view controller before use it, try this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        DetailTableViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        // Get the object for selected row
        Youga *object = [yougaArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc getCategory:object];
    }
}
```